# Given that $\log \sin x + \log \cos x = -1$ and that $\log (\sin x + \cos x) = 1/2(\log (n-1)$, find $n$.

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

Given that $\log(\sin x) + \log(\cos x) = -1$ and that $\log (\sin x + \cos x) = 1/2(\log (n) - 1)$, find $n$.

I have no clue where to even start with this.

Comment: I see two versions of the last tem / argument to $\log$. Which one is correct?

Comment: Ya, I accidentally first wrote log(n-1), but it is actually log(n)-1. You can still use Karn's method below to solve the equation with log(n)-1 also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\log(\sin x) + \log(\cos x) &= -1\tag{1}\\
\log (\sin x + \cos x) &= \frac12\log (n-1)\tag{2}
\end{align}

From $(1)$,
$$\log(\sin x \cos x) = -1$$
then
$$\sin x \cos x = e^{-1}$$

So you have

\begin{align}
\log (\sin x + \cos x) &= \frac12\log (n-1)\\
2\log (\sin x + \cos x) &= \log (n-1)\\
\log (\sin x + \cos x)^2 &= \log (n-1)\\
(\sin x + \cos x)^2&=n-1\\
\sin^2x+\cos^2x+2\sin x\cos x &=n-1\\
1+2e^{-1}&=n-1\\
\end{align}

Comment: Wait, oops! For the second equation it should be log (n) - 1. My bad!

Comment: Still, helped me get the answer, thanks!